# How to Shorten "Ibidem" to "Ibid"

Tags: biblatex, natbib, biber, biblatex-chicago

I'm putting the final touches on the dissertation, and, perhaps unwisely, I updated Latex via Tex Live Utility. Now citations that had previously said "Ibid" read "Ibidem" Does anyone know what I need to do to get it back to the abbreviated version "Ibid"? Here's my header. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{yalephd}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{longtable,tabularx,ltxtable}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[autostyle=false]{csquotes}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}

\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\mdseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\mdseries}


\addto\captionsngerman{% Replace "english" with the language you use
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
    {Table of Contents}%
}

\addto\captionsngerman{% Replace "english" with the language you use
  \renewcommand{\partname}%
    {Part}%
}


\addto\captionsngerman{% Replace "english" with the language you use
  \renewcommand{\chaptername}%
    {Chapter}%
}

\addto\captionsngerman{% Replace "english" with the language you use
  \renewcommand{\tablename}%
    {Table}%
}

\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{5pt}
\setlength\cftbeforesecskip{4pt}
\setlength\cftbeforesubsecskip{4pt}

\emergencystretch=1em

\setlength{\cftchapindent}{4em}
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{5em}
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{6em}

\DeclareCaptionFont{black}{\color{Black}}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}

\newcommand{\foo}{\color{Black}\makebox[0pt]{\textbullet}\hskip-0.5pt\vrule width 1pt\hspace{\labelsep}}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.4}\arrayrulecolor{Black}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false, font=black, labelfont=sc, labelsep=quad, belowskip=1ex}

\expandafter\def\expandafter\quote\expandafter{\quote\onehalfspacing}
\doublespacing

\usepackage[notes,natbib,isbn=false,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago} 
\DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{cms-german}
\renewcommand{\citet}{\Autocite}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{cbyeditor}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{cbyeditor = {ed.}}

\NewBibliographyString{cbyeditor}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{cbyeditor = {ed.}}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{ }

\DeleteQuotes
```

Comment: Off-topic but still of interest: You shouldn't load the `xcolor` and `colortbl` packages independently. To get optimal cooperation of the packages, use a single `\usepackage` instruction, *viz.*, `\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor}`.

Comment: Unless you are writing following the old orthography rules (pre-1996), you want `\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{cms-ngerman}`. Unfortunately, the code you showed us here is not an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) at all, neither can we compile it, nor does it show the problem even if it is changed so that it compiles. Please consider adding a proper MWE to your question, so we can help you more efficiently. You could try with `\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{ibidem= {ibid\adddot}}` (or `english` if `ngerman` doesn't work).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Sorry I did not provide a MWE. '\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{ibidem= {ibid\adddot}}' did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

That should be the default actually, something weird might be going on in your document of which you don't show everything in the code in your question (there everything looks innocent enough, but it can't really be tested).

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{ibidem= {ibid\adddot}}
```

Should definitely get you back to 'ibid' for ibidem citations both in the long and short form, i.e. regardless of your `abbreviation` setting.